# User specific data for items in a REST api

Tags: rest, api, stateless

In a REST api what is the most efficient way to handle user specific data for items?

For example, let's say there are `item` resources that can be favourited. A list of items can be accessed by:

```
https://myservice.com/api/items (Full list)
https://myservice.com/api/items/{id} (Single item)
```

Which returns

```
{
  { 'name': 'name 1' },
  { 'name': 'name 2' },
}
```

Each item can be favourited by a user (`https://myservice.com/api/user/{id}`) and a list of these favourites would be available at:

```
https://myservice.com/api/user/{id}/favorites
```

This whole setup is stateless; however, there may be hundreds of favourites and retrieving a full list may not be needed.

Q: Whilst maintaining a stateless system what is the best way to combine getting an item with the user specific data?

i.e. Is it sensible, or plausible, to get a user-specific list of items:

```
https://myservice.com/api/items?user={id}
{
  { 'name': 'name 1', 'isFavourite':true },
  { 'name': 'name 2', 'isFavourite':false },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Whilst maintaining a stateless system what is the best way to combine getting an item with the user specific data?

Think about how you would do it on a web site.  That's how you do it in REST; you just need to make it machine readable.

> This whole setup is stateless; however, there may be hundreds of favourites and retrieving a full list may not be needed.

In which case, you can distribute the list across multiple resources, and then use [paging](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005) to assist the consumer in finding the resource that returns the next/previous page of the list.

> Is it sensible, or plausible, to get a user-specific list of items

Yes, of course.  The key idea to recognize is that your REST API is part of your integration domain; you *pretend to be* a site full of "web pages", and translate the manipulation of the web resources into actions/queries in your application.